# Cannot solve an trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry, problem-solving

I have an equation that reads like this:

$$\frac{l \cdot \sin{\alpha} + ((h - 2 \cdot r) \cdot \cos(\frac{\alpha} { 2}) + 3 \cdot r - r \cdot \cos(\alpha))}{ 2 \cdot \sin{\frac{\alpha} { 2}}}= w$$

I would like to solve it symbolically for $\alpha$, however, by using sympy, sagemath, mathematica, mathcad no solution can be found. I am only interested in $0<\alpha<\pi$ range and only in real solutions. All other variables are positive reals.

If I plot this equation by inserting arbitrary values following plot can be seen:
[image: a graph]

From the plot, it does not seem like a complicated curve and it looks similar to 1/x. Why is it that I cannot find a solution, and what should I do to be able to derive one?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Consider to use something like $t=\tan(x/2)\;\Rightarrow \sin(x)=2t/(1+t^2)$ and $\cos(x)=(1-t^2)/(1+t^2)$

Comment: The symbolic algebra packages probably struggle because there are so many unsolvable possibilities depending on $l,h,r,w$. Just put $\alpha=2\theta$, multiply up and write everything in terms of $\sin(\theta)$.

Comment: It may look similar to $1/x$ but if you extend the $\alpha$ axis you'll see the periodic nature of sine and cosine come in.

Comment: When you plot did you use radians for the trig functions? It seems that you might be using degrees resulting in a much smoother curve.

Comment: yes, this is radians, l=0, r=0.05, h=0.26

Answer (score 4):

Just to expand on my comment, let $\alpha=2\theta$. Your equation is
$$l\sin 2\theta+(h-2r)\cos \theta+3r-r\cos 2\theta = 2w\sin\theta$$

Using double angle formulae, this is

$$2l\sin \theta \cos \theta +(h-2r)\cos \theta+3r - r\left(1-2\sin^2 \theta\right) = 2w\sin\theta$$

Substituting $x=\sin\theta$,
$$(2lx+h-2r)\sqrt{1-x^2}+3r - r\left(1-2x^2\right) = 2wx$$

You can expand this into a quartic in $x$ and solve from there, but it's not very nice.

For reference, the fully expanded version with solution is [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%283r%20-%20r%281-2x%5E2%29%20-%202wx%29%5E2%20-%20%282lx%2Bh-2r%29%5E2%281-x%5E2%29).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Were you able to obtain the solution for x yourself? Mathematica still cannot solve for me...

Comment: Yes - or rather, I was able to cajole Wolfram|Alpha into doing it. I've added a link. It's...pretty disgusting. What's the context for this equation? It may be easier to make sense of it from that.

Comment: It is an equation for a geometrical shape composed of circles, ellipses and straight lines where w is the maximum width of this shape given an arc length (alpha) of the circles in radians, the length of straight segments (l) and height of the shape (h). To derive the width was a breeze, but I see that expressing alpha is not so much

Comment: By the way thanks for the solution! will try it out in the weekend

Answer (score 2):

You cannot solve symbolically because you need to deal with a quadric (4th-order polynomial).

If you zoom out you will see the complexity arise

[image: fig1]

Take the equation and move the denominator on the right-hand-side to bring the equation into the following form:

$$ A \cos \tfrac{\alpha}{2} + B \sin \tfrac{\alpha}{2} + C \cos \alpha + D \sin \alpha + E = 0 $$

where $A \ldots E$ are coefficients based on the parameters given.

Next, the problem needs to be expressed in terms of simple angles, and so use the substitution $\theta \rightarrow \tfrac{\alpha}{2}$, or

$$ A \cos (\theta) + B \sin (\theta) + C \cos (2 \theta) + D \sin (2\theta) + E = 0 $$

and using the trig identities $\cos(2 \theta) \equiv 2 \cos^2 \theta - 1$ and $\sin(2 \theta) \equiv 2 \sin \theta \cos \theta$

$$ A \cos (\theta) + B \sin (\theta) + 2 C \cos^2 \theta 
 + 2 D \sin \theta \cos \theta -C + E = 0 $$

Now use a tan-half-angle substitution

| Substitution(s) |
| --- |
| $t = \tan \left( \tfrac{\theta}{2} \right)$ |
| $ \theta = 2 \tan^{-1}(t)$ |
| $\cos \theta = \tfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ |
| $\sin \theta = \tfrac{2 t}{1+t^2}$ |

which transforms the equation into

$$ \small A \left( \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} \right) + B \left( \frac{2 t}{1+t^2} \right) + 2 C \left( \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} \right)^2 \theta 
 + 2 D \left( \frac{2 t}{1+t^2} \right) \left( \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} \right) -C + E = 0 $$

and finally, eliminate the denominators by multiplying both sides and expanding out

$$ \small (A+C+E)+(2 (B+2 D)) t+(2 (E-3 C)) t^2+(2 (B-2 D)) t^3+(-A+C+E) t^4 = 0 $$

which is a 4th-order polynomial in terms of $t$.

If you do find a solution (numerically or whatnot) then you go back to $\alpha$ with

$$ \alpha = 2 \theta = 2 ( 2 \tan^{-1} t) = 4 \tan^{-1} t $$

---

Tan-half-angle substitutions are widely used in robotics to transform trig expressions into polynomials.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and explanation of how to approach the problem! Will try it out in the weekend